# Compare text between cell pairs and conditionally write to other cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, text, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet as follows:

```
    A          B        C        D           A1         B1         C1
1  Edd       Eddie     Edd      Edd    
2  Tom       Hill     Hill      Tom       
3  Gilly     Trom     Hill      Hill
4  Abd       Chikku   Apple     Chikku   
5  Rear      Back     Back      Back
```

I want to compare D1 with A, B, C and write the results as `10` in A1, B1, C1 respectively.
Conditional formatting

I tried `=IF($D1=A1,10,0)`  but only background color appeared and not `10`.

**Expected Result Table**

```
    A          B        C        D           A1         B1         C1
1  Edd       Eddie     Edd      Edd          10         0          10
2  Tom       Hill     Hill      Tom          10         0           0
3  Gilly     Trom     Hill      Hill         0         0           10
4  Abd       Chikku   Apple     Chikku       0         10           0
5  Rear      Back     Back      Back         0         10          10
```

Comment: your question is not very clear, if you want to compare D1 with ABC and write 10 then just write 10 in those cells.  Read your question again and rewrite it so it is clear what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Please try (maybe in E1):

```
=IF($D1=A1,10,0)
```

and copy this across and down to suit.

[image: SO28725292 example]

Comment: I have tried but not getting 10 number only getting background color

Comment: Do you want to BOTH show the number 10 AND get the cell to change the background to red? If this is the case, the two steps would have to be done separately. First, use @pnuts function in the cells, then use a conditional format that colors when the cell = 10. If I misread the question, I apologize.